# Apache FileETags directive

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have requested by auditor to Disable inode-based ETag generation in the Apache  by adding the

> FileETag MTime Size

is this apply on all Apache version? I have version 2.2 do i need that? if so how I can do that.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - in [2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#fileetag), `INode` is excluded by default.  In [2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag), the default is `FileETag INode MTime Size`.  You'll need to specify the excluding directive in the context desired; just putting it in the server config will suffice.

Comment: thanks Shane, so simply add 'FileETag INode MTime Size' inside httpd.conf at any lines will be ok?

Comment: @dan As long as it's not within a block for something else (like a vhost, directory, or module), then yes, that should work fine.